# I have a service which connects to SNF and runs queries periodically, but fails OCSP after 24-72 hours

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use#establishing-connections) leaves alot to be desired, but I create a connection pool as specified:

```
snowflake.createPool(snowflakeConfig, poolConfig);
```

From that object, when the time comes, I .use() like so:

```
async executeSql(statement: string, callback: any, bindings?: string[]) {
    var options: any = {
        sqlText: statement,
        complete: callback,
    };

    if (bindings) {
        options['binds'] = bindings;
    }

    this.Snowflake.use(async(con: any) =>{
        const call = await con.execute(options);
    });
}
```

This works, but for how long is anyone's guess. I've just seen it fail after what I believe to be a little over 24 hours. Now when executeSql() is called, I get the following error messages:

```
NetworkError: Network error. Could not reach Snowflake.

{"level":"ERROR","message":"[10:27:16.2716 PM]: OCSP validation failed: Error [OCSPError]: Invalid validity. Valid from: 2023-02-20T04:36:19.000Z , Valid to: 2023-02-21T16:36:19.000Z\n at createError (/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/errors.js:537:15)\n at exports.createOCSPError (/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/errors.js:369:10)\n at Object.verifyOCSPResponse (/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/agent/cert_util.js:326:24)\n at getOcspResonseAndVerify (/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/agent/socket_util.js:320:31)\n at vali"}
```

I can find very little about how to use the snowflake-sdk library, other than SNF's own documentation, and a Medium article that doesn't demonstrate any sort of sophistication.

Am I supposed to be resetting the connection pool periodically? Keeping track of how many non-stale connections I have left? Can this just not be used in a long-running context?

Do the data warehouse folks just have my account misconfigured?

I am able to find little to explain just how I am screwing this up, or how non-idiots (I don't claim to be in this category) avoid screwing it up.

Snowflake does not seem to conform to my expectations on how a connection pool is supposed to function.

Comment: What about using [CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#client-session-keep-alive) to keep the session alive? Have you tested it?